# How to convert a list to a map with a set value in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Hosting> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Hosting(1, "liquidweb.com"));
list.add(new Hosting(2, "aws.amazon.com"));
list.add(new Hosting(3, "digitalocean.com"));
list.add(new Hosting(2, "aws.amazon.com"));
```

I want to convert the above list into a `Map<Integer, Set<String>>`

```
1 -> {"liquidweb.com"}
2 -> {"aws.amazon.com"}
3 -> {"digitalocean.com"}
```

How can I do the conversion in Java 8?

Comment: Will there ever be more than one string that map to the same ID? In your example `2 -> aws.amazon.com` is repeated but the end result is still a 1-to-1 mapping.

Comment: @JohnKugelman good should!. I'd "assume" there will be cases where there is more than one string that map to the same id given the corresponding value of the key is a `Set<String>` but if not then the OP is probably better off going with `Map<Integer, String> result = list.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Hosting::getId, Hosting::getValue, (l, r) -> l));`

Answer (score 5):

Using `toMap`:

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> result = list.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Hosting::getId,
                        e -> new HashSet<>(Collections.singleton(e.getValue())),
                        (l, r) -> {l.addAll(r); return l;}));
```

or:

Using `groupingBy` with `mapping` as the downstream collector:

```
Map<Integer, Set<String>> resultSet = list.stream()
          .collect(groupingBy(Hosting::getId, 
                       mapping(Hosting::getValue, toSet())));
```

Personally, I prefer the latter as it's more readable.